# First row not added in the calc

Tags: c#, gridview, sum

For some reason the first row of my gridview is not getting added in the sum of the column.

**Code here:**

```
double total = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView4.Rows)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string sNum = e.Row.Cells[6].Text;
        double sum;
        if (double.TryParse(sNum, out sum))
        {
            total += sum;
        }

        TextBox21.Text = total.ToString("c");
        //GridView4.FooterRow.Cells[6].Text = total.ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of the first row? Is it a number?

Comment: Yes, I have another gridview that has checkboxs when ticked the row populates to the 2nd gridview and the column must sum. does not matter what item populates, the first row is not calculating.

Comment: My guess is somehow `double.TryParse(sNum, out sum)` returns false. What's the exact value of the first row?

Comment: I fixed it. e. was the issue.